# Whitelisting parameters for multiple objects from nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms

I have a form that aims to update a collection of objects in an association:

```
<%= form_tag(url: update_parent_children_path(parent_id: @parent.id), method: :put) do %>
  <% @children.each do |child| %>

    <%= fields_for "children[]", child do |cf| %>

    .... Fields for form
```

In the parameters, this comes across as:

```
params[:children] --> 
  {"1" =>{"foo"=>"x", "bar"=>"y", "baz"=>"z"},
   "2" =>{"foo"=>"x", "bar"=>"y", "baz"=>"z"},
   "3" =>{"foo"=>"x", "bar"=>"y", "baz"=>"z"}}
```

I know to whitelist one instance of the object, I would use:

```
params.require(:child).permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

Is there a comparable method to permit the full list of children params?

For reference, the update block of code I'll be using:

```
def update_children_on_parent
  @children.each do |child|
    child_params = update_params.select{|key, value| key == child.id}
    child.update(child_params)
  end
end
```

where update_params is the whitelisted children parameters list

Comment: In the parent controller `params.require(:parent).permit(:child => { :foo, :bar }` should allow you pass nested params. Also read about `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Answer (score 0):

In the update function, permitted params individually rather than as a predefined whitelist.

Given

```
params[:children] -->
{
  "1" =>{"foo"=>"x", "bar"=>"y", "baz"=>"z"},
  "2" =>{"foo"=>"x", "bar"=>"y", "baz"=>"z"},
  "3" =>{"foo"=>"x", "bar"=>"y", "baz"=>"z"}
},
```

update function works as follows:

```
@children.each do |child|
  child_params = params[:children].select{|key, value| key == child.id.to_s}["#{child.id}"]
  child.update(child_params.permit(:foo, :bar, :baz))
...
```